# Maven host is innaccesible when trying to build project

Tags: android, maven

I have just try to build my project and this problem is appearing, my mates have the problem too.

Have fabric changed any url?

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.
>   Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
>        Required by:
>            blabla-blabla-android-app:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
>   Failed to list versions for io.fabric.tools:gradle.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Connect to fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com:443 [fabric-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.80.32] failed: Operation timed out

Gradle Script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning and it seems that it is fixed now. The maven repository was down.